# Yii2 why the field form does not appear?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have this code in my _form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'receiver_id')->widget(Select2::classname(),[
    'data'=>ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['category' => 'customer']),'username','username'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'select student id ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
        ],

 ]); ?>
```

its working fine at first but when I add this layout code in the controller it didn't show the dropdown

```
public function actionCreate()
{    $this->layout = 'lecLayout';
    $model = new Privatemessage();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

if i do not put the layout code its working fine. but i need the form display in the layout.

[image: this is what happens when I run the code. the receiver id does not appear]

Comment: I think it's a typo, you pass in your view id => $model->id and in your form you use receiver_id, i think you have to use  $form->field($model, 'id')

Comment: Or show us the view code

Comment: there is nothing like `::classname()` but `::className()`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam It does not matter - methods names are case insensitive in PHP.

Comment: @raynaqarla Your layout probably have some styles which hides this input. It is impossible to guess what rule caused this without access to your CSS files.

Comment: lol sorry @rob006 i guess i needed some coffee at that time